# React-Redux with DataTables - Need to Pull Updated State

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, datatables, react-redux, state

Hey all first post so please forgive the maybe less than ample detail. In short I'm setting up a site that uses the library DataTables and implementing with React-Redux. When the user clicks on the link I load the component, hit a thunk that pulls the required data on the API side and returns it. I've confirmed that the data IS indeed coming back via the thunk.

My issue comes in when I try to now display that data. I will need to massage the data into a 2-d array so I thought I would write a function to take care of that piece, only issue is when I pass the part of state I think its grabbing too early and pulling an empty array BEFORE the thunk triggers. So in the end what I'm seeing is that I pass in `overview` and log it and get `[]` not `[returned data here]`. I'm a bit new to the DataTables library but think this is less about that and more React. Any help would be appreciated!

Heres the component, successfully displays if I feed it just junk data so again think its more on the React and Async maybe?

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(data[0]); // also logs [], but should be data
  }, 2000);
};

export const SpecialistTodayOverview = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const user = useSelector(state => state.currentUser);
  const overview = useSelector(state => state.SPOverview);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getSPOverview(user));
    $(document).ready(() => {
      console.log(overview); //logs [], should contain data
       parseData(overview) // see above
      $('#test').DataTable({
        columns: [
          {
            title: 'Col1',
          },
          {
            title: 'Col2',
          },
          {
            title: 'Col3',
          },
        ],
        data: [
          [1, 2, 3],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9],
        ],
        dom:
          '<"row"<"col-sm-4"B><"col-sm-4 tabletitle"><"col-sm-4"f>>t<"row"<"col-sm-4"i><"col-sm-8"p>><"row"<"col-sm-12"l>>',
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      Need to put SpecialistTodayOverview here
      <table id="test" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SpecialistTodayOverview;
```

Comment: Try using this example for reference by replacing `useEffect` with `useCallback`. i.e.

import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
export const Counter = ({ value }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const incrementCtr = useCallback(
    () => dispatch({ type: 'increment-counter' }),
    [dispatch]
  )
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{value}</span>
      <IncrementButton onIncrement={incrementCtr} />
    </div>
  )
}
export const IncrementButton = React.memo(({ onIncrt }) => (
  <button onClick={onIncrt}>Increment</button>
))

Comment: Not sure I'm following, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: My bad, it's badly formatted but what I meant to say was if you want to fetch your data from redux you need to have async behavior of your dispatch callback. Try logging `overview` out of the `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access overview immeditealy after you call the dispatch function, but the state will not be updated since you are dispatching an action to fetch data from server. You can use async/await to block execution till dispatch function resolves.

```
useEffect(async () => {
 await dispatch(getSPOverview(user));
 $(document).ready(() => {
   console.log(overview); //logs [], should contain data
   parseData(overview) // see above
```

You need to update your getSPOverview to return a promise or declare it as async as follow:

```
getSPOverview = async () => {
  const overview = await fetchOverview();
  setOverview(overView);
}
```

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately I'm getting the following error:
`
React Hook "useSelector" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
`

Comment: Yeah my bad, i use redux connect instead of useSelector so i am not familiar with it. I updated my answer with another solution.